# Improve performance of mysql query for a table on google cloud sql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with "137678997" records and no UNIQUE, PRIMARY keys. Here is my table description.

```
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| domain        | varchar(50)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| guid          | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sid           | varchar(100)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| url           | varchar(2500) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ip            | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| is_new        | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ref           | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| user_agent    | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| stats_time    | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country       | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| region        | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city          | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city_lat_long | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email         | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Indexes on domain, email, stats_time

And my sql query is

```
SELECT p1.guid, p1.email,MAX(mx_time) as latest_time, 
       p1.city_lat_long, p1.user_agent, 
       p1.city, p1.region, p1.country 
FROM(
  SELECT guid, email,
         MAX(stats_time)as mx_time, 
         city_lat_long, user_agent, 
         city, region, country 
    FROM page_views 
    WHERE domain ='our' 
      AND DATE(CONVERT_TZ(stats_time,'+00:00','+05:30')) 
        BETWEEN DATE('2013-06-21 00:00:00') 
        AND DATE('2013-08-21 00:00:00') 
    GROUP BY guid) p1 
WHERE p1.email !="" 
GROUP BY email 

UNION ALL 

SELECT p2.guid, p2.email,
       mx_time, p2.city_lat_long, 
       p2.user_agent, p2.city, 
       p2.region, p2.country 
FROM(
  SELECT guid, email,
         MAX(stats_time) as mx_time, 
         city_lat_long, user_agent, 
         city, region, country 
  FROM page_views 
  WHERE domain ='our' 
    AND DATE(CONVERT_TZ(stats_time,'+00:00','+05:30')) 
      BETWEEN DATE('2013-06-21 00:00:00') 
      AND DATE('2013-08-21 00:00:00') 
  GROUP BY guid) p2 
WHERE p2.email="";
```

Sorry for this big query, the intention is to get latest visitors(Max(stats_time)) of a domain. Here I used UNION ALL because I have to get all the anonymous users too where I cannot group them by email id.

I also did test with a simple select columns without UNION ALL, this taking more than 15 minutes. How can I improve the performance of the queries on my table?
It is actually a google cloud sql with D2 Tier(1 GB RAM). Really appreciate your suggestions, am very new to Mysql .

EDIT ::

```
SELECT p2.guid, p2.email,mx_time, p2.city_lat_long, p2.user_agent, p2.city, p2.region, p2.country
FROM
(SELECT guid, email,MAX(stats_time)as mx_time, city_lat_long, user_agent, city, region, country FROM page_views WHERE domain ='our' AND DATE(CONVERT_TZ(stats_time,'+00:00','+05:30')) BETWEEN DATE('2013-06-21 00:00:00')  AND DATE('2013-08-21 00:00:00') GROUP BY guid) p2 where p2.email=""
```

This query gives me rows with visitors who doesnot have email.

And

```
SELECT p1.guid, p1.email,MAX(mx_time) as latest_time, p1.city_lat_long, p1.user_agent, p1.city, p1.region, p1.country
FROM
(SELECT guid, email,MAX(stats_time)as mx_time, city_lat_long, user_agent, city, region, country FROM page_views WHERE domain ='our' AND DATE(CONVERT_TZ(stats_time,'+00:00','+05:30')) BETWEEN DATE('2013-06-21 00:00:00')  AND DATE('2013-08-21 00:00:00') GROUP BY guid) p1 where p1.email !="" GROUP BY email
```

This one give me rows which are not empty and grouped by email.
And the two were UNION ALL because i need all of the Anonymous visitors + known visitors(email != "") in the particular date range.

Thank you :)

Comment: You have a lot of function in _Where_ clause what is bad for your query and actually Union All, Group By, it better for you to add table structures and your expecting result, and we will try to change this query

Answer (score 1):

it's difficult to improve query perfomance because you have a lot of function in *Where clause* what is bad for your perfomance, *Max function and Group by* in subquery i think it bad too and Union All which gives you duplicate . Actually i can recomend you  avoid datetime converting in *Where* clause [Here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) useful link how to avoid it.

And i want to add some of advice how can you get *latest visitors(Max(stats_time)) of a domain* without Max and Group By - Better to use *Order By desk and Limit*.

If i misunderstand you , you can add your Logic and expected result and we will try to change your query.

Thank you.

**Update**

This is your first query

```
SELECT p2.guid, p2.email,mx_time, p2.city_lat_long, p2.user_agent, p2.city, p2.region, p2.country
FROM (SELECT guid, email,MAX(stats_time)as mx_time, 
                    city_lat_long, user_agent, city, region, country 
      FROM page_views 
      WHERE domain ='our' 
            AND DATE(CONVERT_TZ(stats_time,'+00:00','+05:30')) 
            BETWEEN DATE('2013-06-21 00:00:00')  AND DATE('2013-08-21 00:00:00') 
      GROUP BY guid) p2 
where p2.email=""
```

You can change it to

```
SELECT guid, email,MAX(stats_time)as mx_time, city_lat_long, user_agent, city, region, country 
FROM page_views 
WHERE domain ='our' 
  AND DATE(CONVERT_TZ(stats_time,'+00:00','+05:30')) 
  BETWEEN DATE('2013-06-21 00:00:00')  AND DATE('2013-08-21 00:00:00')
  AND email=""
GROUP BY guid
```

At this point you dont need two query just and *email=""* to where clause

**Update *II***

You should avoid converting data in Where clae like this `DATE(CONVERT_TZ(stats_time,'+00:00','+05:30')) BETWEEN DATE('2013-06-21 00:00:00')  AND DATE('2013-08-21 00:00:00')`

Can we change it to `stats_time > '2013-06-21 00:00:00' AND  stats_time <= '2013-08-21 00:00:00'`

As i told you should read **[This Link](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)** it will be good for you!

Comment: Hello The,Thanks for the quicker response ,
Ive edited my post to let my intention with the query .Please let me know if that can be improved more.

Comment: @vinay patlolla the first query you need for all visitors last date or just you need only last visitor ? because you use Group by

Comment: Hi The,I am grouping by guid ,where i get a result which has combination 
of rows with existing visitors and anonymous visitors.So from this result i need unique visitors (the second query from edit where only am grouping by email) and all the anonymous ppl(first query in edit).Please let me know if you need any clarification in this .Thanks

Comment: @vinay patlolla i have updated first part of your quetions. Could you check  it ? Thank

Comment: Hi The ,thanks for the update .But the updated query is not as quick as which i used(taking twice execution time of mine) .I think group by and finding an empty email is quicker than finding all empty email's .

Comment: I dont know how it posible, you are grouping All Email it takes a lot of time, in my query i am filtering this email and grouping only _email=""_ emails

Comment: Am sorry abt the statistics ,you are right The.Can you also suggest me in Date conversions :)

Comment: `DATE(CONVERT_TZ(stats_time,'+00:00','+05:30'))` could you explaine this logic? we should avoid this converting

Comment: Yaee i should avoid as it is converting the date in each record by adding the offset.Instead of this can i minus 5.30 from startdate and end date that to be compared ?

Comment: Yeap it would be better

Comment: Hey The...I have an issue here .The datetime fields are being saved in UTC standard .so i will have to apply the offset before  comparing for the date ranges selected by the user .we should atleast avoid it using in where clause .Do you find any alternative ?Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81241/discussion-between-the-and-vinay-patlolla).

Answer (score 0):

1- Can you do the filtering by email in the inner queries?

```
SELECT p1.guid, p1.email,MAX(mx_time) as latest_time, 
   p1.city_lat_long, p1.user_agent, 
   p1.city, p1.region, p1.country 
FROM(
SELECT guid, email,
     MAX(stats_time)as mx_time, 
     city_lat_long, user_agent, 
     city, region, country 
FROM page_views 
WHERE domain ='our' 
  AND DATE(CONVERT_TZ(stats_time,'+00:00','+05:30')) 
    BETWEEN DATE('2013-06-21 00:00:00') 
    AND DATE('2013-08-21 00:00:00') and email !=""
GROUP BY guid) p1
WHERE p1.email !="" 
GROUP BY email 
UNION ALL 
SELECT guid, email,
     MAX(stats_time) as mx_time, 
     city_lat_long, user_agent, 
     city, region, country 
FROM page_views 
  WHERE domain ='our' 
AND DATE(CONVERT_TZ(stats_time,'+00:00','+05:30')) 
  BETWEEN DATE('2013-06-21 00:00:00') 
  AND DATE('2013-08-21 00:00:00') and email =""
GROUP BY guid
```

2- Use [explain statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to see the execution plan and indices used.

3- Add an index over other fields that you filter by like email. I don't know the cardinality of domain (the only indexed field in your queries), but I don't think it is enough to exclude large amounts of data in your table to make selection fast. You can check its cardinality yourself using [show index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-index.html) query.

Comment: Hi Adel ,Thanks for the quick response .
1.I cannot filter by email as it is not provided before querying ,
  i will have only domain .But Group By email is to get unique visitors